# Upload com ajax e java

Tags: java, ajax, upload

Estou fazendo um upload de imagem com ajax (já testei sem ajax e funcionou).

JS:

```
$("#upload").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: $("#controller").val(),
      type: "POST",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      success: function(json) {
        if (json.status) {
          iziToast.success({
            title: 'Ok',
            message: json.message,
            icon: "fa fa-check",
            timeout: 2500,
            position: "center",
          });
        } else {
          iziToast.error({
            title: 'Erro',
            message: json.message,
            icon: "fa fa-times"
          });
        }
      },
      error: function() {
        iziToast.error({
          title: 'Erro',
          message: "Erro ao fazer requisição",
          icon: "fa fa-times"
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

O problema é que quando chego na parte de receber o file em java:

```
List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
```

recebo o erro:

> the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed
>   stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
>   charset=UTF-8

Já coloquei o `enctype: 'multipart/form-data'` na requisição ajax, mas mesmo assim o erro periste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estou respondendo minha pergunta, porque futuramente alguém pode ter a mesma duvida, ou queira saber como fazer upload de arquivos com **Ajax** e **Java**

**1 - Adicione o Html**

```
<form id="form" action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="imagem" id="file"/> 
   <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
   <span id="msg"> </span>
</form>
```

**2 - Js** 
*Com Jquery*

```
$("#form").on("submit", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: "upload",
                method: "POST",
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                success: function (json) {
                    // Aqui você receberia do json um status talvez, que diz se foi feito o upload com sucesso ou não. No nosso caso vamos simular que sim.
                    $("#msg").text("foi");
                }
            });
        });
```

**É importante** ressaltar que, não podemos capturar a imagem para enviar com a requisição ajax com `$("#file").val()` isso devolveria só um caminho simbólico da imagem, você pode testar usando `console.log($("#file").val())`. Para recebermos realmente a imagem eu utilizei o Objeto **formData**, que recebendo como parâmetro o nosso Formulário, ele faz toda a parte de pegar a imagem em si e deixar no jeito para ser enviada pro servidor (creio que existem outras formas de receber realmente a imagem).

Tudo ok, vamos para o back end

**3 - Java**

OBS: coloque a anotação `@MultipartConfig()` na sua servlet..

Irei colocar partes do código e explicar

```
// pegando a imagem
Part imagem = request.getPart("imagem");
```

Aqui simplesmente estamos criando um objeto Part, usando o `request.getPart()`, no parâmetro do método, coloque o nome do atributo `name` que usou na tag `input type="file"`

```
    //verificando se a pasta onde o upload será salvo existe, se não existir vamos criar
    File pasta = new File("C:"+File.separator+"upload");
    if(!pasta.exists()){
    //não existe, bora criar
    pasta.mkdir();
    }
```

**Não** estamos usando `getRealPath` para criar o caminho da pasta que usaremos para salvar as imagens por motivos que podem ser lidos [neste post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664579/recommended-way-to-save-uploaded-files-in-a-servlet-application/18664715#18664715), aconselho que vocês também não usem o `getRealPath`.

Muito bem, se a pasta existir...

```
else {
    // criando referencia do arquivo
    File img = new File("C:" + File.separator + "upload" + File.separator + "teste.jpg");
    // criando arquivo em si
    img.createNewFile();
}
```

Quando criamos um File `new File(caminho e nome do file)`, na verdade, a classe File só cria um link vazio, "assumindo" que o File já existe, mas isso não cria nenhum arquivo, para realmente criamos o arquivo, usamos o método `createNewFile()`, isso cria um arquivo vazio. (se você depurar o código, e parar depois da linha do `img.createNewFile()` poderá ver isto, um arquivo criado, porém vazio).

Muito bem galera.. pasta criada, arquivo criado, agora vamos simplesmente salvar a imagem dentro do arquivo !

```
        // gravando imagem no arquivo
        imagem.write("C:" + File.separator + "upload"+ File.separator+"teste.jpg");
```

Pronto, ao ser executado, o método `writer` escreve os dados do `Part` dentro do arquivo, isto é, ele grava a imagem dentro do arquivo, se você verificar e estiver tudo correto, o arquivo deverá estar no diretório `C:/upload/` com a imagem gravada nele.

**Nota:**

- o método `writer` pode disparar uma Exception, caso o arquivo não exista.
- Caso o arquivo já exista (no nosso caso, `teste.jpg`) o writer irá sobrescrever os dados antigos, com os novos, isto é, irá substituir a imagem atual, pela que acabou de ser enviada

  Bom.. é isso pessoal, está é uma maneira simples de fazer upload de imagens com java, espero que isto ajude

Answer (score 0):

tente colocando este atributo:

```
contentType: "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8"
```

ou

```
processData: false,
contentType: false
```

Comment: tentei e não deu certo..

Comment: Man tem um exemplo bem legal. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1020950/A-Simple-Method-to-Upload-Files-by-jQuery-Ajax-Cal

Answer (score 0):

Para receber no servlet deve fazer assim:

```
Part arquivo= request.getPart("nome_arquivo");
InputStream sInputStream = arquivo.getInputStream();
```

Comment: Estou usando o Commons-FileUpload

Comment: @RickPariz se quiser da uma olhada, tenho um projeto que no git público com upload de arquivo. https://gitlab.com/Jeffersonvh/spolifly/

Comment: você usa ajax ?

Comment: @RickPariz Não, mas se o problema é na hora de receber vale a pena dar uma olhada

Comment: qual o nome da classe responsavel pelo upload ? estou procurando lá mas não acho nada

Comment: @RickPariz https://gitlab.com/Jeffersonvh/spolifly/blob/master/src/java/servlet/CadastraMusica.java

Comment: obrigado, vou dar uma olhada